# How to add buttons to a NSSplitter handle?

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to add buttons, or to draw inside the handle of an NSSplitter ?

I don't only want to draw over the control like it's done in XCode (for errors handling, see second image); I also want to add features to the split view. For example, in this case, I would like the double arrow to swap the two views.

[image: A mockup of my idea]

[image: An line draw in the scroll bar]

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `NSSplitView` and override `drawDividerInRect:` and `dividerThickness` to create the illusion that you want, and `adjustSubviews` to relocate any custom clickable views that you put at the same location.

Comment: Do you have any specifics on what to do in `adjustSubviews` to relocate the clickable views? Although it's being called, I don't see any changes in my UI.